# How to set "Root POM" path for TFS project in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, tfs, configuration, pom.xml

How to set "Root POM" path for TFS project in Jenkins? I have been using Jenkins to run my selenium automation scripts for a while.But I am planning to integrate it with TFS now.I added TFS plugin in Jenkins and also configured Source Code Management as TFVC. But when I give path to POM, it says "No such file:"  Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path of pom.xml in relation to jenkins workspace. Check this case: [No such file: ‘pom.xml’ error in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157672/no-such-file-pom-xml-error-in-jenkins)

Comment: I tried that way too and still it says "No Such file: ' ' "

Comment: Following is the way I configured the project                                                       Source Code Management
TFVC
Collection URL:
https://***teamservices.visualstudio.com/
Project path:
$/QAScripts/ProjectName

Build
Root POM:ProjectName/pom.xml                                                                  @NOTE:I dont have the pom in my workspace                                                  Thanks

Comment: @laxmi Is pom.xml existing in source control ($/QAScripts/ProjectName)? What's the detail of build log?

Comment: Yes..It is under $/QAScripts/ProjectName .It says "No Such file: " when I configure the project itself                                                                                
Created workspace 'Hudson-Selenium-MASTER'.
Getting version 'C***' to 'C:\Users\***\.jenkins\workspace\Selenium'...
Finished getting version 'C***'.
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file C:\Users\***\.jenkins\workspace\Selenium\$\QAScripts\ProjectName\pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?     
This is my console output. Please help..Thanks

Comment: Do you have rights to access folder or file path where pom.xml is stored?

Comment: @laxmi Why there is $ in path? can you map the source to c:\Users***\jenkins\workspace\Selenium\ProjectName?