# How to Specify subfolder for Maven in Jenkins?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I have the following folder structure:

- Finance/Code
- Finance/Docs
- Finance/SQL

The GIT repository is created on Finance folder. I configured Jenkins to look at GIT repository in /Finance. The maven pom file is located in Finance/Code. When I run the Jenkins build, I got this error:

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
>   is no POM in this directory
>   (/Users/Macpro/.hudson/jobs/Publishing/workspace). Please verify you
>   invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

How to configure Jenkins to look at */Finance/Code* for the pom file?

Comment: Why not putting a pom into `Finance` directory and call Jenkins on the root location of the workspace and build everything in one go?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I could, but seemed better to be configured without adding unnecessary files.

Comment: This not an unnecessary file cause you define the whole project...etc. only a single call instead of three?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As illustrated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162030/6309), you should fill out the Root POM field with a relative path:

[image: root pom]

Relative means from the Jenkins workspace:

```
Code/pom.xml
```

(no leading `/`) That is, if `Finance` is the root of your workspace.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in pipeline script?

Comment: @yuxh Not sure: see if cnoverting the job to a pipeline yields the answer: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Convert+To+Pipeline+Plugin

Comment: To do it in pipeline script use a wrapping dir('./module') {}

Answer (score 1):

The last answer worked for me, but the settings image is a little bit different as I am using the latest version of Jenkins. So I am posting it here as it may help someone. [image]